# Azure SQL Server firewall not allowing operation to connect even though option is set to yes in firewall settings

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying to import my local SQL server database into Azure and I have all the requirements (storage, bacpac file, etc). When I try to import the db, I am getting the error below.

> The Azure SQL Server firewall did not allow the operation to connect.
> To resolve this, please select the "Allow All Azure" checkbox in the
> Sql Server's configuration blade.

I have already checked yes on the **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** option in the firewall settings and added my client IP. Is there something behind the scenes preventing it from allowing access? I am running my SQL server on a Docker container.

**Imported bacpac file**
[image: Local DB Azure Data Studio imported bacpac file]

**Import Operation Azure**
[image: Import DB Operation Azure]

**Import Error**
[image: Import Error]

**Firewall Settings**
[image: Firewall Settings]

Comment: do you import the database in code level?

Comment: @LeonYue what exactly do you mean?

Comment: which way did you use to backup the database?

Comment: I exported a bacpac file from the data-tier application wizard in azure data studio.

Comment: Sounds like you are blocking yourself when you are trying to perform the import.  I assume you are doing this via browser and portal.azure.com?  You may need to switch the firewall option to allow Public access so that your browser can reach and perform the intended operation.  I fell across something similar with another Azure service. I had thought if I allowed Azure services access to do things that I could just just click a button and make it do it. But I found that my browser was acting as a client of sorts and needed to be able to access things via Public access.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense the browser needs that access in order for the import to succeed. I am performing the import on the portal. Where would I allow public access in Azure?

Comment: @MPagan please try set the firewall from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255.

Comment: @LeonYue I added a new rule from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. No luck.

Comment: @MPagan It's so strange, can you show us the login screenshot?  Where is the bacpac file? You can connect to the Azure SQL database correctly, but when import the bacpac file, it gives the error?  Is this helpful: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/cjn-how-to-connect-your-microsoft-sql-server-docker-container-with-azure-data-studio/?

Comment: @LeonYue check screenshots above

Comment: @MPagan thanks for sharing. I haven't met this situation for now. Really sorry!

Comment: This is very strange because with same setting(without adding 0.0.0.0 IP) I took backup of dbs on blob storage before 4 month ago and was successfully completed the tasks, Today I start doing this and it gives me the same error, ? any reason,

Comment: @SaadAwan thats pretty weird. Yea I don't understand whats going wrong with it. Maybe its the bacpac file? Idk lol

Comment: @MPagan do you have other Azure SQL database? Can you test with another one with same firewall settings?

Comment: @MPagan I have 8 Databases under same database server, and all have same IPs I allowed under them with no difference, concerned is that all are working fine before 3, 4 months back but yesterday they do problem. Interesting thing is that After another attempt backup succeed:) .

Comment: @LeonYue I do but its prob going to give the same error since its under the same server.

Comment: @SaadAwan thats interesting, why is that? Also I provided an update for both you and Leon in my post above.

Comment: @MPagan I mean connect to the other Azure SQL  Server, if anything changes. Create a cheapest server to test that. If it still not works, maybe only the Azure support can give you the root cause and help you solve it.

Comment: @MPagan I don't think this is related to IP restriction as far as I understand from your screenshot. Do you have any SQL users inside your database that you try to import? If so, please delete them from your local, then create the bacpac and try importing new backpac again. This might fix your problem. Let me know the good news! :)

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral this is interesting! I might try removing all the users from my db just to test if it imports or not. This may have been the problem as well, feel free to provide that as another answer below.

Answer (score 4):

After a week of trial and error, the database imported fine with no problems so I'll answer my question. What is interesting is that I don't have a concrete answer to my question since I don't know exactly why it did, but I'll give two tips anyway.

1. It might have been the cache on Azure's side. I got in contact with
   an Azure rep recently and they stated that the cache may have not
   updated yet. Clearing your cache could be the source of the problem
   as well. To clear the cache see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-flushauthcache-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current).

   ```
   DBCC FLUSHAUTHCACHE;
   ```
2. Creating a new rule that spans from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 in
   your firewall settings.

Feel free to provide more solutions in the answers. Like I said, it was likely the cache on their side. It was really odd that it didn't work for a while, even with the firewall settings configured correctly.

Comment: Please avoid adding the IP range from 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. It makes your Azure SQL vulnerable. Just curiosity, is it fixed after you delete the local SQL users?